# Перевод счётчика количества просмотров

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Вероятно, после очередного обновления потерялась локализация строки "просмотрен %count% раз".

> [image: просмотрен 16 times]

Comment: [meta-tag:статус-завершено] ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Строку с множественными формами перевёл](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/114201669?key=b84178ecfcfe437e75bacdc01a0aaed5). Перевод слетел из-за [добавления разделителя разрядов](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251510/3240681) в кол-во просмотров.

Comment: Weird. The old string should've been something like `**#__count# times**` (still bold). The actual change is comma separators in view counts > 1000, which changed the string so that pluralization still worked correctly. Here's the diff of the change: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8kSM.png. Thanks for translating.

Comment: @AdamLear да. Я малость промахнулся с диагностикой. Просто этот ответ не отредактировал. На MSE отписался в [комментарии](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296968/reason-to-make-viewed-count-bold/296969#comment963542_296969).

Comment: Если честно, то я тоже не знаю, зачем там жирный шрифт прописан. Наверно когда-то раньше он был нужен, а потом дизайнеры изменили стиль без HTML. Я просто оставил это как было на всякий случай. :)

Comment: @AdamLear по ссылке на MSE вроде бы объясняется, что без жирного там будет цвет серый, а не черный. Такой вот хитрый способ трансформации стиля в цвет :)