# Дубликат вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, дубликаты

Вопрос [Как сделать, чтобы Dropdown на Boostrap всегда был открыт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/677675/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-dropdown-%D0%BD%D0%B0-boostrap-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82)

Уже задавался – 
[Как в моб. версии Bootstrap сделать так, чтобы при открытии Navbar вложенные Dropdown уже были раскрыты?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605505/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-bootstrap-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-navbar-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-dro/607551)

Я сам не могу подать тревогу

[image]

Comment: Эм. Вы набрали 1к репутации и до сих пор не знаете, что нужно с дубликатами делать?

Comment: Меня ограничили

Comment: в чем вопрос-то? Или это теперь мода по всем дубликатам, вопросам на закрытие писать на мету? поставил флаг и иди дальше, раз ограничили. Напиши комментарий под вопросом, в конце концов

Comment: Я сам не могу подать тревогу

Comment: Господи, из меты уже какую-то помойку делают. Один спрашивает, можно ли задать такой-то вопрос на основном сайте, другой постит  чтоб дубликаты на основном сайте закрыли...WTF?

Comment: А в чём причина ограничения на подачу тревог? Как оно выглядит-то?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/0dRizKH.png

Comment: И из этого Вы сделали вывод, что стоит предложить тревогу в виде вопроса на Мете? :)

Comment: Это временный запрет, он пройдет через 19 часов. Просто немного подождите. Не стоит использовать мету как трекер тревог.

Comment: @PashaPash ограничение уже 3 день

Comment: Причем через мобильное приложение тревогу подать можно

Answer (score 6):

Если система намекает вам, что ваши тревоги слишком часто отклоняются, то пытаться добавить ещё одну тревогу да ещё через место не предназначенное для этого -- выглядит не очень уместно.

На вашем месте я вижу следующие неплохие варианты действий:

1. Подождать неделю, пока не закончится блокировка. После этого запостить сообщение о дубликате самостоятельно. Дубликат -- это не спам, не оскобления или иной неподходящий контент, может спокойно и подождать неделю.
2. Зайти в [чат на сайте](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) и там задать вопрос не дубликат ли и указать, что сами вы не можете подать тревогу по определённым причинам. Вопросы оперативного модерирования сайта весьма часто решаются именно в чате.

На будущее, если опять придётся столкнуться с подобным рекомендую придерживаться именно подобного подхода.

Comment: «На Мете приветствуются любые вопросы каким-либо образом касающиеся Stack Overflow на русском.»

Comment: @Alex78191, но в вашем сообщении не было вопроса…

Comment: @mymedia на мете таких много https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5418/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: @Alex78191 это сообщение о дефекте